# The JTable Edit/UnEdit Code Not Working For Re Arranged JTable Columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I am using the following code for Edit/UnEdit for my JTable Columns, but when the user re-arranged the columns the following code is not working
SSCCE of the code is following:

```
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
    boolean flag = false;
            if (isEdit == true) {    
                if ((vColIndex == tblItem.getColumn("Design").getModelIndex())
                        || (vColIndex == tblItem.getColumn("ChangedCategory").getModelIndex())
                        || (vColIndex == tblItem.getColumn("Amount").getModelIndex())) {
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    flag = true;
                }
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }    
            return flag;
  }
};

JTable table2 = new JTable(model);
}
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for `JTable/XxxTableModel` stored as `local variable`

Comment: @mKorbel i have edited posted SSCCE.

Comment: `i applied your solution but it is not working`, not working almost in cases, disclaimer was described in my 2nd. answer (both I deleted) now we are returns from the end back to start, reason for asked SSCCE, I'm out of this thread

Comment: deleted posts and answers are visible for all users with reputations points >10k

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir: You may need to convert model/view indexes, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16191431/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that model and view indexes are *not* equivalent. As noted [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting),

> `JTable` provides methods that convert from model coordinates to view coordinates — `convertColumnIndexToView` and `convertRowIndexToView` — and that convert from view coordinates to model coordinates — `convertColumnIndexToModel` and `convertRowIndexToModel`.

The tutorial section discusses [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) rows, but the principle applies to columns as well. Absent a [complete example](http://sscce.org/), it's hard to be sure.

Comment: But in my case i have to use
vColIndex == table.convertColumnIndexToView(tblItem.getColumn("Design").getModelIndex())