# Easy way to get the data from selected columns in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and want to get the data from each selected column. The columns are selected by mouse clicks. So, if there are  5 columns selected, the output has to be 5 string arrays.

I'm trying to do this by `MouseListener`, but I can get only the clicked cells, not the entire column.

Comment: But if you know which cell was clicked, you know the column where it belongs, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but the problem is that I don't know how to print the entire columns, which were selected. I'm not experienced with jtables.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried; two columns and one row should be enough to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `JTable.getSelectedColumns()`, but it returns the selected column indexes, so you need to access the `TableModel` (package `javax.swing.table`)

```
int[] columns = jtable.getSelectedColumns();
TableModel model = jtable.getModel();
int rowcount = model.getRowCount();
String[][] output = new String[columns.length][rowcount];
for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
    for (int row = 0; row < rowcount; row++){
        int column = jtable.convertColumnIndexToModel(columns[i]);
        output[i][row] = model.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
    }
```

Comment: You forget to convert from view coordinates (`JTable`) to model coordinates (`TableModel`)

Comment: johnchen902: Try dragging columns to see the problem; more on @Robin's point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16191431/230513).

Comment: Your code will only work if you do not re-arrange the columns in your `JTable`. If you would move e.g. the first column to the end of the table your code will fail. You need to use the `JTable#convert*IndexToModel` methods. An example can be found in the class javadoc of the `JTable` class

Comment: Note that you make a similar mistake for the rows. You do not consider the scenario where rows are filtered out. You need to retrieve the row count from the model rather then from the table

Comment: @Robin Oh my goddess! What situations else am I missing?

Comment: Nothing as far as I can see

Comment: Thanks for the help! One more thing, how can I restrict the mouse clicks to one for each column?