# Add and remove from one Table To another

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am facing a problem with the functionality of removing a row(s) form one table view to another table view currently I have two button one add row form the bottom table to the above and the next add from the above the the botton. the button that add from bottom to top called add and the button that add from top to bottom called remove in both once the row is copied across it get deleted from the original table.

The problem I am facing is:

when I add all the row from the bottom table to the top table
if I sort Column 0 in top table ,then try to remove the row from the top table to the bottom table 
the row do not get deleted from the top table although it is added in the bottom table.

Could you please Help me solve this problem or advice me on a better way?

Here is my current code:

Remove button:

```
btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    spTable.removeAll();
    x = resultTable.getSelectedRows();
    String[] cName= {"Column 0","Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5","Column 6","Column 7","Column 8"};
    if(rTable.getRowCount()==0){                
       model=addToNew(resultTable,x,cName,model);
    }else{ model =addToExisting(resultTable,rTable, x, model);
                 }  
    deletRows(x,resultTable);
    rTable.setModel(model);
    JScrollPane spS = new JScrollPane(rTable);
    rTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(290);
    spS.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    spS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,200));
    rTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    spTable.add(spS);
            validate();
    }});
```

Add button:

```
 btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    panel.removeAll();
    x = rTable.getSelectedRows();
    String[] cName= {"Column 0","Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5","Column 6","Column 7","Column 8"};
    if(resultTable.getRowCount()==0){
                model=addToNew(rTable,x,cName,model);
    }else{ model =addToExisting(rTable,resultTable, x, model);
        }   
    deletRows(x,rTable);
    resultTable.setModel(model);
    JScrollPane spS = new JScrollPane(resultTable);
    resultTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(290);
    spS.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    spS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,170));
    panel.add(spS);
    resultTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    validate();}});
```

deletRow

```
public void deletRows(int[] selected, JTable t){
 for(int i = selected.length-1;i>=0;i--){
   int y = selected[i];
    ((DefaultTableModel)t.getModel()).removeRow(y);
    validate();}}
```

/**
 * this method allow to add rows to an New table 
 */

```
       public DefaultTableModel addToNew(JTable t1,int[] selected,String[] ColName, DefaultTableModel m){
String[] name = ColName;
int col = name.length;  
m =new DefaultTableModel();
for(int i= 0;i<col;i++){
 m.addColumn(name[i]);
        }
Object[] data= new Object[col];
    for(int i =0; i<selected.length;i++){
        int y= selected[i];

        for (int z =0; z<col;z++){  

                        if( t1.getValueAt(y, z)!= null){
                            String value = t1.getValueAt(y, z).toString();
                            data[z]= value;
      }else{
                data[z]=null;
            }
        }
        m.addRow(data);
        }

    return m;

}
```

/*** this method allow to add rows to an Existing table */

```
public DefaultTableModel addToExisting(JTable t1,JTable t2, int[] selected, DefaultTableModel m){


     m =(DefaultTableModel)t2.getModel();
    Object[] data= new Object[m.getColumnCount()];

    for(int i =0; i<selected.length;i++){
    int y= selected[i];
    for (int z =0; z<m.getColumnCount();z++){  
                    if( t1.getValueAt(y, z)!= null){
                        String value = t1.getValueAt(y, z).toString();
                        data[z]= value;                         
       }else{
        data[z]=null;
       }
    }

    m.addRow(data);
}

    return m;

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16191431/230513) on converting coordinates.

Comment: @trashgod  Thanks for the hint I manage to fix the problem it was due to index changing table view to model view